# Solr Having clause in Faceting

Tags: solr

Would like to check, is it possible to put the having clause `(having sum(fieldC) > 1000)` in the following example in Solr Facet or JSON Facet query?

I'm using Solr 6.4.1.

```
select fieldA, fieldB, count(*), sum(fieldC), avg(fieldY) 
from collection1 
where fieldC = 'term1 term2' 
group by fieldA, fieldB 
having sum(fieldC) > 1000 
order by sum(fieldC) asc 
limit 100
```

Regards,
Edwin

Comment: Why cant you use range function for this?

Comment: We are thinking of doing it with JSON Facet, as JSON Facet is said to have a better performance than normal range query.